# Build Dockerfile in repo and use as image for later steps in GitHub

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

I'm moving some projects from Jenkins to GitHub CI.

Jenkins has a very useful construct, `agent { dockerfile true }`, which first checks out the `Dockerfile` and anything not listed in the `.dockerignore`, runs `docker build .`, and runs the remaining build steps inside a container that uses the freshly built image, so I have a convenient one-liner that makes the appropriate build environment available.

I have managed to replicate this on GitLab with [about sixty lines of boilerplate code](https://gitlab.com/GyrosGeier/elim/-/blob/main/.gitlab-ci.yml) that add an extra stage to generate an image named `$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA` and push it that can then be used from the later stages, and that also pull the image corresponding to the last commit on the main branch before so it can hopefully reuse some layers.

On GitHub, I am completely lost how to do this correctly. Presumably I'd pull the same trick as on GitLab and use a separate stage that generates an image named after my repository (so it ends up inside the repo's package registry) and use the commit checksum as the tag name.

There is [Publishing Docker Images](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-docker-images), which seems to be a good start, but I don't see how it would reuse layers (our cloud bill is high enough as it is already), or how I could extend it to support multiple platforms later.

Looking at example C/C++ projects, these all seem to just specify an external image that has no build instructions in the project repo, or install packages as part of the build.

- Is there a best-practice strategy for describing the build environment as a Dockerfile inside the repository itself?
- Is there a shorter command to generate an image from the current repository and make it available to later stages of the same build?
- Is there a way to run the image and build stages on the same agent to avoid copying megabytes of data around?